# How to declare $title in my html code?

Tags: php, html

So I have header.php file with my header and page1.php, page2.php, page3.php with my content. Every page starts from

```
<?php include_once("header.php") ?>
```

But title is always static in my code. I tried to add `<title><?php $title_value ?></title>` to my header.php, and

```
<?php $title="Contacts"; include_once("header.php") ?>
```

to my page1.php but title is invisible. It seems like `$title` didn't exist. How can I fix it and add different titles to my pages?

Comment: Or change it to `<?= $title_value ?>`

Comment: @chris85 Jeezes, thanks) Add to answers. Easy points for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php $title_value ?>` does nothing. You need to echo/print the value in the `header.php`.

```
<title><?php echo $title_value; ?></title>
```

In `header.php` you also should include a check incase you forget a title in a file.

```
$title_value = empty($title_value) ? 'Default Title' : $title_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You only declared the variable.
You didnt print or echo it.

Use:

```
<?= $title; ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php echo $title; ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php print $title; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

first you have to echo the value of the title like that:

```
 <?php echo($my_var) ;?>
 // or
 <?=$my_var?>
```

after to change the title of your page u can pass a $_GET param to your html title value ( not the better way but the easier )

ex:

```
 // on the fist page
 <a href="/myurl?title=page2">
 // on the second page
 <?php echo($_GET['title']) ;?>
```